# How to use Future in database access

Tags: java, database, scala, slick, future

I'm using slick in a mixed Java/Scala program.
The Java code needs to get some data from the database. 
As I understand, the recommended way is to get a Future from the database, but how do I proceed from here? Am I forced to wait for the result (using blocking Await.result)? can I make the Java act similarly to Scala with onComplete?

current (blocking) code:

slick [Scala]:

```
def getUser(email: String): Option[User] = {  
    val findUser = users
        .filter(_.email === email)
        .result
        .headOption

    Await.result(db.run(findUser), Duration(1000, "millis")) // blocking :-(
}
```

Java:

```
if(UsersDataBase.getUser(email).isDefined()) {
...
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried, and indicate where that code doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert (or wrap) Scala `Future` to Java `Future`. The same with `Option`

In this days you can use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat)

The simple example is:

```
import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters._
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage
import scala.concurrent.Future


val javaFuture:CompletionStage[String] = Future.successful("ok").toJava
```

Comment: If the Java code has nothing to do until the data from the database is received, is there any reason not to block the Java thread? Is this situation better than blocking the Scala (database) thread?

Comment: The only one reason to block is when you run some application that definitely does all steps one by one in the whole application. It's definitely not about web server because there are a lot of "process threads" that compete for the resources, and waste some resource in the time when it could be used by other is not the best idea.

It's your code in the current function "nothing to do" but it could be some other function that wants something to do, but could not because the thread is blocked.